# Reading Excel File In Python xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm really struggling to read an excel file in Python which is something I need to be able to do for coursework that I have set and I have found a method of doing it using xlrd however, I cannot get it work. I used cmd to install xlrd (pip install xlrd) and it was successful however, I am still unable to read Excel sheets into Python and I am unsure as to why it is not working, below is my code:

```
import xlrd

file_location = "C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/DADSA 17-18 COURSEWORK A MALE PLAYERS.csv"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

Now every tutorial that I have watched this method has worked however, when I try to do it I get an error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Data Structures Assignment 1\Tennis.py", line 3, in <module>
  workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
  File "C:\Users\Sean\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 162, in open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\Sean\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
  biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\Sean\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1271, in getbof
  bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\Sean\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1265, in bof_error
  raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
  xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF      record; found b'MP01\r\nMP'"
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: It looks like your filepath is a .csv as opposed to a .xlsx or .xls, is this a problem for xlrd? would you rather open a .csv with the csv module?

Comment: Oh yeah you could possibly be right! Keen eye mate I'll see if I can figure that out how to use the csv module

Comment: @new_to_coding `xlrd` cannot read csvs, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to my comment I thought I would show some basic code to use the csv module to iterate over rows, also, pythons csv module documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

```
import csv
import xlrd

file_location = "C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/DADSA 17-18 COURSEWORK A MALE PLAYERS.csv"

if file_location.endswith(".csv"):
    with open(file_location) as fp:
        for row in csv.reader(fp):
            # do something with rows
elif file_location.endswith((".xls", ".xlsx")):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    # do something with workbook
```